# Selecting a committee where two persons do not wish to serve together

Tags: combinatorics

---

I am writing this post after reading this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493206/selecting-a-committe-with-two-women-refusing-to-sit-together)

---

> A committee of 6 is to be chosen from 10 men and 7 women so as to contain at least 3 men and 2 women. In how many different ways can this be done if two particular women refuse to serve in the committee together?

---

I approached this by making different cases.

**Case I** - *When there are 4 men and 2 women in the committee*

There are 10 men and we have to choose any four from them. Hence $ \binom{10}4$.

Let the two women who hate each other be *x* and *y*.

Now 2 women can be allowed to serve in the committee. Keeping the restriction in mind, if *x* serves in the committee then *y* will not. Now we have to choose 1 from the remaining 5 women (excluding *x* and *y*). Similarly for *y*. Hence, $2\binom{5}1 $.

Our restriction would be satisfied even when both *x* and *y* are not in the committee. So we can choose 2 women the from the remaining 5 (excluding *x* and *y*).
$$\binom{10}4 \left[2\binom{5}1 + \binom{5}2\right]$$

**Case II** - *When there are 3 men and 3 women in the committee*

$$\binom{10}3\left[2\binom{5}2 + \binom{5}3\right]$$

Using [Rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum), we can deduce that the total number of arrangements satisfying the condition provided is $$\binom{10}3\left[2\binom{5}2 + \binom{5}3\right] + \binom{10}4 \left[2\binom{5}1 + \binom{5}2\right] = 7800$$

---

**My questions**

- Is this correct?
- Is there any better method?

---

Comment: You could (alternatively) first ignore the restriction and then later subtract all virtual committees that include the both women that hate eachother. Unfortunately I must go now and have not the opportunatity to check your answer.

Comment: Is the total arrangement (without restrictions) = $\binom{10}3 * \binom{7}2 * 12$ ?

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest drhab approach. The total number of possible arrangements is
$${{10}\choose{4}}{{7}\choose{2}}+{{10}\choose{3}}{{7}\choose{3}}$$
and the total number of possible arrangements that include the 2 woman who hate each other is
$${{10}\choose{3}}{{5}\choose{1}}+{{10}\choose{4}}.$$
So the total number of arrangements satisfying the condition is
$${{10}\choose{4}}{{7}\choose{2}}+{{10}\choose{3}}{{7}\choose{3}}-{{10}\choose{3}}{{5}\choose{1}}-{{10}\choose{4}}=7800.$$

Comment: Why can't the total arrangement (without restrictions) be $\binom{10}3 * \binom{7}2 * 12$? It is $12$ because 5 people are already selected out of 17. Hence, there are 12 people remaining to serve for the last position.

Comment: Because the 5 people selected are not always the same, so you're counting possible committees multiple times. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109999/choosing-a-committee-of-3-members-from-5-men-and-2-women-with-at-least-1?rq=1

Comment: So when I include a women in $12$ and another women in $\binom{7}2$ , there is another arrangement in which I include the 1st women in $\binom{7}2$ and the second in $12$. These two arrangements are the same as same members are being included in the committee. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, you are understanding it correctly.